# alembic can not find python-dateutil

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-3.8, alembic

I am trying to create a simple migration using

```
alembic revision -m "ddl for some migration"
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
FAILED: The library 'python-dateutil' is required for timezone support
```

I have already tried reinstalling python 3.8 using pyenv, and creating fresh virtual environments but nothing seems to work.

When I do pip freeze, I can see `python-dateutil` there, when I go into python shell and import it, it's imported as well but for some reason, `alembic` is unable to find it.

I have tried the latest version of alembic as well as `alembic==1.5.7` and the problem seems to persist.

I have also tried installing it in system python instead of `virtualenv` and even then the problem is same.

I have tried running the following commands and it says I am already updated

```
xcode-select --install
```

Any hints on what else I should try?

Answer (score 1):

#### You can try to install

pip install python-dateutil

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.x, this works:

```
pip3 install python-dateutil
```